# 「ひゃっくり」ってどこの方言？

Tags: dialects

自分が普段使うのは"しゃっくり"です。しかし、しゃっくりと言ったら「ひゃっくりだよ」と注意されたことがあります。辞書ではそうなってはいないみたいです。

ひゃっくりとはどこの方言なのでしょうか。それとも、方言ですら無いのでしょうか。

Comment: 関東の方で少しなまりがあったらしい…

Comment: 方言ですね。...........

Comment: @user4092 ありがとうございます、どこの方言かご存知ですかね？　自分が調べた限りでは、関東の方だと思いますが…

Comment: あと、その内容が分かれば回答していただけると嬉しいです。Acceptします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ひゃっくりは甲州弁、山梨県の方言です。
標準語では「しゃっくり」が正しいです。

100回繰り返すからひゃっくりという説もあるので、指摘する人もいるでしょう。

Comment: It appears that you used the following site as a source: http://stop-hiccups.com/category3/entry11.html. Please see [How to reference materials written by others](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) ([日本語訳](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)). You are required to cite sources when quoting, supplying a link if applicable.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.That source from my professor when I learned Japanese.<br>Your link also same meaning.